# Is there any formula showing the relationship between $V$, $A$ and $G$ as mentioned below?

Tags: mass, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy, volume

We all know that if we fill a cylinder with water and then drop the egg into the water it sinks but when we add some three tsp of salt the egg floats.

Let,

$V=$ volume of the cylinder.

$A=$ Volume of the object submersed inside water.

$G=$ Gram of salt to be mixed

Suppose that salt is the only thing we have and it is very expensive and we cannot not waste even a gram of salt. In that case is there any formula which shows the relationship between the terms V, A and G.
Please guide me.

(We could solve this by the density formula but i need to know if the formula as asked above exists)

Comment: The problem is finding the increase in the volume of the water when the salt is added.

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: This is a non-ideal mixing problem, meaning that 1 liter of water + 1 kg of salt does NOT give you the expected total volume.  Also note that when you mix salt and water, it is very easy to separate the mixture by boiling the water to dryness.  None of the salt will boil away.

Comment: Sorry but I think that you are diverting from the question